# Is there a linked list predefined library in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, abstract-data-type

Is there a linked list in C++ that I could just #include? Or do I need to create my own if I want to use one?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As [daniel notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735324/is-there-a-linked-list-predefined-library-in-c/1735329#1735329), yes, [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). Usage would be:

```
#include <list>
// ...
std::list<int> listOfInts;
listOfInts.push_back(1);
// ...
```

And so on.

You can find a complete list of STL classes [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html). The section you're after is 3.2, Container classes. Another useful reference of the C++ Standard Library is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: This is a double linked list, which allows for Bidirectional traversal, the SGI STL (and some others) also define single linked lists, see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html for example.

Comment: But the element in the list has no info about its predecessor and its successor... That may be required...

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <list>
```

Answer (score 5):

In c++ we have the STL, Standard Template Libraries which do contain a a lot of implemantations of popular data structures and algorithms like stacks, queues, **linked lists** and popular searching and sorting algorithms even.....

As already told by daniel you can include it by #include< list>

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old, anyway maybe it worth to update it as it's up on the search hits when you look for STD and linked lists:

In addition to what already said by the others (use [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) for a double-linked list), for the most common use case of a single-linked list, [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) should be preferred, because it's optimized for single-linked lists specifically.

Answer (score 4):

[STL List](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completing awareness of "common link lists that are out there", the Qt library defines its own [QLinkedList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinkedlist.html) as part of its container classes (QMap, QString, etc.)

They support both standard iterators, as well as [Java-Style Iterators](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#java-style-iterators), which have an easy-to-use syntax:

```
QLinkedList<QString> list;
list << "A" << "B" << "C" << "D";

QListIterator<QString> i(list);
while (i.hasNext())
    qDebug() << i.next();
```

> **Update:** I posted this answer originally in 2009, to bring attention to the Qt class.  In the post-C++11 world, with things like [range-based `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), you can generally get even better syntax than the Java-Style iterators...without sacrificing performance to do so.
>
> So while this was probably worth bringing up for completeness when I posted, today I'd not be likely to mention it.  Unless you have some strange reason not to, just use the standard library's singly linked list ([`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)) or doubly linked list ([`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)).

Comment: Recommending not using language features...hm.

Comment: No, I recommend developing an awareness of alternatives (especially when those alternatives are used in practice by many professional C++ programmers).